# Binding custom events of custom elements in MVVM Pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism, livecharts

I'm trying to bind the "DataClick" event of LiveChart's Cartesian Chart element using MVVM pattern.

I have my Charts.xml like this:

```
<ContentControl Grid.Row="0">
        <lvc:CartesianChart x:Name="ContrastChart" Series="{Binding ContrastSeriesCollection}">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="DataClick">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ChartDataClick}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </lvc:CartesianChart>
    </ContentControl>
```

This is my ICommand ChartDataClick on my ViewModel:

```
        public ICommand ChartDataClick {
        get
        {
            if(_dataClickCommand == null)
            {
                _dataClickCommand = new DelegateCommand( 
                    () => 
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Data Clicked!");
                    } 
                    );
            }

            return _dataClickCommand;
        }
    }
```

If I switch e.g "DataClick" for "MouseEnter" I get my command fired.

So I'm assuming that the problem is that the DataClick is a custom event.

Anybody knows a workaround for this?
I really tried everything I could find on Google that could help, but nothing so far...

LiveCharts Events: [Events Documentation](https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Events%20and%20Ui%20Elements)

Comment: this is finally supported... https://github.com/beto-rodriguez/Live-Charts/issues/42

Answer (score 3):

The `EventTrigger` doesn't discriminate.

We can check this by implementing [MyButtonSimple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752288(v=vs.110).aspx) which has a custom Routed Event `Tap`.

We can go from handler in code behind

```
<custom:MyButtonSimple 
    x:Name="mybtnsimple" Tap="mybtnsimple_Tap"
    Content="Click to see Tap custom event work">
</custom:MyButtonSimple>
```

To a ViewModel ICommand

```
<custom:MyButtonSimple 
    x:Name="mybtnsimple"  
    Content="Click to see Tap custom event work">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Command}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</custom:MyButtonSimple>
```

And everything works as expected

The shortcoming of these triggers is that they have to be placed on the [UIElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.raiseevent(v=vs.110).aspx) raising the event.
In other words, they ignore Bubbling or Tunneling events. That's why there is no `Interaction.Triggers` alternative for:

```
<Grid custom:MyButtonSimple.Tap="mybtnsimple_Tap">
    <custom:MyButtonSimple 
        x:Name="mybtnsimple"  
        Content="Click to see Tap custom event work">
    </custom:MyButtonSimple>
</Grid>
```

To sum it up, the `DataClick` event isn't raised on the `CartesianChart` (but further down the Logical Tree) and therefore you can't handle it this way.

Comment: So I won't be able to handle this event the way is coded right now? Or you think is possible with a helper or something? If I change the code of LiveCharts to produce a routed 'DataClick' event would make a difference?